# Maximum value from the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I needed the maximum value from the particular JSON object. I needed it to make a scale for apple and banana's for d3 from its maximum value

So how do I get the maximum value of apple and banana from this JSON. I don't need the month name. I don't want to use any for or while loops.

`var arr = [
  {
    "date":"Jan",
    "values": [
    {"name":"apple","value":100},
    {"name":"banana","value":200}
    ]
  },
  {
    "date":"Feb",
    "values": [
      {"name":"apple","value":300},
      {"name":"banana","value":455}
      ]
  },
  {
    "date":"Mar",
    "values": [
      {"name":"apple","value":588},
      {"name":"banana","value":700}
      ]
  }
  ];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) after finding the fruit from `values` with [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var arr = [{
    "date": "Jan",
    "values": [{
        "name": "apple",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "name": "banana",
        "value": 200
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb",
    "values": [{
        "name": "apple",
        "value": 300
      },
      {
        "name": "banana",
        "value": 455
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "Mar",
    "values": [{
        "name": "apple",
        "value": 588
      },
      {
        "name": "banana",
        "value": 700
      }
    ]
  }
];

const maxVal = (fruit) => Math.max(...arr.map(d => d.values.find(v => v.name === fruit).value));

console.log(maxVal('apple'));
console.log(maxVal('banana'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could something like this:

```
const max = (list) => list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let apple = cur.values[0].name === 'apple' ? cur.values[0] : cur.values[1];
  let banana = cur.values[0].name === 'banana' ? cur.values[0] : cur.values[1];
  acc[0] = acc[0] < apple.value ? apple.value : acc[0];
  acc[1] = acc[1] < banana.value ? banana.value : acc[1];
  return acc;
}, [0, 0]);
```

It returns an array, the first item is the max number of apples, the second is the max  number of bananas.

Example

```js
var arr = [{
    "date": "Jan",
    "values": [{
        "name": "apple",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "name": "banana",
        "value": 200
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb",
    "values": [{
        "name": "apple",
        "value": 300
      },
      {
        "name": "banana",
        "value": 455
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "Mar",
    "values": [{
        "name": "apple",
        "value": 588
      },
      {
        "name": "banana",
        "value": 700
      }
    ]
  }
];

const max = (list) => list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let apple = cur.values[0].name === 'apple' ? cur.values[0] : cur.values[1];
  let banana = cur.values[0].name === 'banana' ? cur.values[0] : cur.values[1];
  acc[0] = acc[0] < apple.value ? apple.value : acc[0];
  acc[1] = acc[1] < banana.value ? banana.value : acc[1];
  return acc;
}, [0, 0]);

console.log(
  max(arr)
);
```

Comment: This won't help. Its because you are using 0 and 1 index. We are never sure, what the index would be for apple and banana. It can change.